# Group products and display quantity from the products array using Vue3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs3

I managed to count every repeated element in my array, now I just want to display only one and each product quantity quantity.

This is what I have now:

[image]

I have a function which I am exporting from a file called `Helpers.js` and then using in my Vue component.

**Helpers.js:**

```
export const groupBy = (arr, criteria) => {
    return arr.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
        const key = typeof criteria === 'function' ? criteria(item, index) : item[criteria];

        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = [];
        }

        obj[key].push(item);
        return obj;
    }, {});
}
```

**Orders Component:**

```
import { groupBy } from "@/Utils/Helpers";
... rest of the component...

const groupedOrders = computed(() => groupBy(props.order.products, (product) => product.id));
```

This is in my template:

```
<div class="mt-5 mx-8" v-for="products in groupedOrders">
                {{ products.length }}
                <OrderItem  
                    v-for="(product, index) in products"
                    :product="product"
                    :key="index" 
                />
            </div>
```

This is the data which I am loggin in the console:

[image]

Any clue how to make it to show only one Modi and display the quantity, something like `Modi (Qtty. 4)`

Comment: Please add the related HTML code as well, so we can see how you build the actual frontend.

Comment: Added  the HTML of my Order component into the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your code iterates through the products array that you create one tile for each product inside the products array due to the `v-for` on your `OrderItem` component.

To achieve what you want to have, you simply have to take one element of the array and output the array's length, rather than traversing through it.

```
<div class="mt-5 mx-8" v-for="(products, groupIndex) in groupedOrders">
    <OrderItem
        :product="products[0]"
        :key="groupIndex" 
        />
    <span>Quantity: {{ products.length }}</span>
</div>
```

Keep in mind, that you need to be sure, that the `products` array is not empty in order to access the first element without an error. If you use the grouping function you provided, this should be fine.

Now what this will most likely do, is add the quantity behind your product tile. In order to print the quantity inside your product tile, you need to provide it to your `OrderItem` component.

```
<OrderItem
        :product="products[0]"
        :key="groupIndex"
        :quantity="products.length"
        />
```

Then in `OrderItem.vue`:

```
... component stuff ...
props: [
    ... your other props ...
    'quantity',
    ... your other props ...
]
```

And in the `OrderItem` template, at the position of your liking:

```
<span v-if="quantity > 0"> Quantity: {{ quantity }} </span>
```

In case you do not provide `quantity`, the `v-if` condition will make sure, that you do not output the quantity text.

Comment: Thank you!, seems to work as expected